# Firebase - Issue Setting up Firebase Cloud Messaging

Tags: firebase

I'm having some difficulty setting up push notifications with my Firebase app. I followed this [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BsCBCudx58g) to the letter on setting up cloud messaging

I'd like mobile devices to be able to receive notifications, so I add the `requestPermssions()` function directly to my index.html

```
<!-- Firebase -->
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/3.4.0/firebase.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/3.4.0/firebase-app.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/3.4.0/firebase-auth.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/3.4.0/firebase-database.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/3.4.0/firebase-storage.js"></script>

...
...

<script>
var config = {
  apiKey: "56sds55hhjh906rwsbghghsd",
  authDomain: "app-33aef.firebaseapp.com",
  databaseURL: "https://app-33aef.firebaseio.com",
  storageBucket: "app-33aef.appspot.com",
  messagingSenderId: "43532673275"
};

firebase.initializeApp(config)

const messaging = firebase.messaging();
messaging.requestPermission()
  .then(function(){
     console.log('Have Permissions!');
     return messaging.getToken()
  })
  .then(function(token){
    console.log(token);
  })
  .catch(function(error){
    console.warn('ERROR: ' + error);
  })

  messaging.onMessage(function(payload){
    console.log('onMessage', payload);
  })
</script>
```

However I'm seeing the following `TypeError`

```
firebase.messaging is not a function
```

After scouring the web I've read that you have to use `firebase-admin` to use the `messaging()` function. I've tried that as well but then I get an `Unexpected token import' error, but that may just be my project setup...

Does anyone have a solution for this? I feel like I'm going in circles here for something very simple

Answer (score 0):

Well, I feel that this was so obvious that I never would have thought about it.

Include the script tag for firebase messaging (oy vey).

```
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/4.2.0/firebase-messaging.js"></script>
```

It would have been helpful to mention this in the video as many others were stumped as well